# Matlab, dos() command : files remain "in use"

Tags: matlab, cmd

After executing some simple commands like

```
dos('copy *.txt new.txt', '-echo')
dos('echo. 2 > EmptyFile.txt', '-echo')
```

I tried to delete the folder in which these files were created. However, Windows gives me the message
"cannot delete "FolderName": the folder is being used by another person/program".
I have to close Matlab to make it work.
How do I solve this? I guess it's something like closing the "session" of cmd commands...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're not showing is the change of working directory to your folder. Windows won't let you delete a folder that a process has as a current working directory.

The solution is simple: change the working directory *out* of that folder. Say:

```
cd('..')
```

Comment: oh, so it's not related to the dos commands. It's just that I am working in that folder with matlab. It would happen even without those   dos commands, right?